# Mypy Optional args vs default values

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I have some code similar to the below one. In `do_something_1`, I want to set the `default_value` for `my_int` to be `None` so that I can do some logic on it later. But `mypy` throws this error:

```
Incompatible default for argument "my_int" (default has type "None", argument has type "MyInt")
```

However, when I change to `Optional` like in `do_something_2`, everything works well.

My questions are:

1. What should the default be in `do_something_1` if `None` is rejected by `mypy` checks?
2. What is the benefit of `do_something_2` over `do_something_1`?

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyInt(BaseModel):
    value: int


def do_something_1(my_int: MyInt = None):
    if my_int is not None:
        print("Value:", my_int.value)
    else:
        print("no value")


def do_something_2(my_int: Optional[MyInt] = None):
    if my_int is not None:
        print("Value:", my_int.value)
    else:
        print("no value")

# do_something_1()
do_something_1(my_int=MyInt(value=1))
# >>> Value: 1
# do_something_2()
do_something_2(my_int=MyInt(value=2))
# >>> Value: 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I omit Optional if I set default to None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732402/can-i-omit-optional-if-i-set-default-to-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, the value `None` which you want to assign as default value, is of a special type `NoneType`, which is not compatible with any other type, to avoid explicitly errors where you call methods on None objects (much like Java NullPointer` runtime errors).

This obviously isn't an issue when using standard Python (which does no checking at all on the types), but poses a problem when using typing.

The possible solutions are:

- Use an `Optional` (as you did, so that your input variable can either be a `MyInt`  or `None`)
- Make `MyInt` inherit from `NoneType` (probably not what you want)